# parse XML into a table

Tags: xml, powershell-3.0

i have this XML and i need to parse it into a table in powershell. i need a few lines of code to put it into a table

```
<RowTypes>
    <RowType Id="70430" Label="JACS Principal Subject (2012/13 onwards)" />
    <RowType Id="70431" Label="Cost Centre (2012/13 onwards)" />
    <RowType Id="3297" Label="Institution" />
    <RowType Id="3298" Label="HESACode Principal Subject" />
    <RowType Id="3299" Label="Cost Centre (2003/04 &amp; before)" />
    <RowType Id="3300" Label="JACS Principal Subject (2006/07 &amp; before)" />
    <RowType Id="3301" Label="Cost Centre (2004/05 to 2011/12)" />
    <RowType Id="3302" Label="JACS Principal Subject (2007/08 to 2011/12)" />
    <RowType Id="3303" Label="Unit of assessment" />
    <RowType Id="3304" Label="UCAS JACS Subject Line (2011/12 &amp; before)" />
    <RowType Id="68689" Label="UCAS JACS Subject Line (2012/13 onwards)" />
</RowTypes>
```

Answer (score 0):

read the content of your file and cast the result as xml :

```
PS>[xml]$x=gc c:\temp\xml.xml 

PS>$x.rowtypes.rowtype | %{ echo "ID=  $($_.Id) LABEL= $($_.Label))"}   
ID=  70430 LABEL= JACS Principal Subject (2012/13 onwards))             
ID=  70431 LABEL= Cost Centre (2012/13 onwards))                        
ID=  3297 LABEL= Institution)
```

Comment: C:\killme
 > $x.rowtypes.rowtype | %{ echo "ID=  $($_.Id) LABEL= $($_.Label))"}
Property 'rowtypes' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At line:1 char:1
+ $x.rowtypes.rowtype | %{ echo "ID=  $($_.Id) LABEL= $($_.Label))"}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict